# Solve differential equation $y''+y=\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I think my answer for this is incorrect, as "graphing" the equation in Desmos after finding $y$ does not show lines on the entire $x$ axis. Here is my approach. First, I need to solve
$$\lambda^2 + 1 = 0 \iff \lambda = \pm i \Rightarrow y_h = c_1\sin(x) + c_2\cos(x)$$

Then,
$$e^0(\cos(2x)+\sin(2x))=e^{\alpha x}(P(x)\cos(\beta x) + Q(x)\sin(\beta x)) \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow \alpha = 0, \beta = 2, P(x) = 1, Q(x) = 1 \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow y_p =A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x) \Rightarrow y_p'' = -4A\cos(2x)-4B\sin(2x)$$

Thus,
$$y_p'' + y_p = \cos(2x)(-4A+A)+\sin(2x)(-4B+B) = \cos(2x) + \sin(2x),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}A = -\frac{1}{3} \newline B = -\frac{1}{3}\end{cases}$$

Finally, $y=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)-\frac{1}{3}\cos(2x)-\frac{1}{3}\sin(2x)$. However, as I said, graphing this using Desmos displays distinct/discrete (not sure this is the correct term) solutions, which means the equation is not correct for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Where could my approach wrong?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in your proposed solution into the differential equation? This is often the easiest sanity check. Also: what exactly did you put into Desmos, and what did it produce?

Comment: @TheoBendit I have no clue why I didn't think of that! Thank you for the help, I now see that, in fact, I accidentally mistyped my equation into Desmos, which led to the wrong graph. Here's what I meant to put into Desmos and how it should look if it is correct (by which I mean that it should look strange because Desmos can't plot the whole plane): https://prnt.sc/dmmBQ9Hm_2NJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that $$y^\prime(x)=-c_1 \sin(x)+c_2 \cos(x)+\frac{2}{3} \sin(2x)-\frac{2}{3} \cos(2x),\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}$$

as well as $$y^{\prime \prime}(x)=-c_1 \cos(x)-c_2 \sin(x)+\frac{4}{3}\cos(2x)+\frac{4}{3}\sin(2x),\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Finally, $$y^{\prime \prime}(x)+y(x)=\cos(2x)+\sin(2x),\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Nothing wrong.